# AngularJS with jQuery for selecting parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm posting my html and directive code. I have two spans, which I have attached `ng-click` to. On `ng-click` I want to check the classes of their parents parent item (`.parent-portlet`), but what I have so far is not working correctly as all of the parent portlets get selected instead of only the current one.

```html
<div class="parent-portlet {{portlet.class}} {{portlet.class2}}" ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)">
  <div class="portlet-titlebar" ng-click="toggleCollapsed($event)">
    <span class="remove" ng-click="removePortlet(portlet)">
     Remove
    </span>
    <span class="add-back" ng-click="addPortlet(portlet)">
     Add Back
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is what I have in my directive:

```js
scope.removePortlet = function(portlet) {
  var port = $('.remove').parent().parent();
  port.addClass('removed');
  port.addClass('edit-portlet');
};

scope.addPortlet = function(portlet) {
  var port = $('.add-back').parent().parent();
  if (portlet.hasClass('removed')) {
    port.removeClass('removed');
    port.removeClass('edit-portlet');
  }
};
```

The problem with this code is that var *portlet* catches all of the portlets(parents) and I want to catch only the one related to the click action. How can I achieve that? I tried to pass this to my jquery select like so:

```
var portlet = $('.add-back', this).parent().parent();
```

but that didn't work. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try use angular.element instead of $ (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: `var port = $(this).parents('.parent-portlet');` ?

Comment: avoid using jQuery. You should us `ng-class` and update the `portlet` classes there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the $event to the ng-click like this:

```
<span ng-click="removePortlet($event)"></span>
```

Then, just modify your code like this:

```
scope.removePortlet = function(ev) {
  var port = $(ev.target).parent().parent();
  port.addClass('removed');
  port.addClass('edit-portlet');
};

scope.addPortlet = function(ev) {
  var port = $(ev.target).parent().parent();
  if ($(ev.target).hasClass('removed')) {
    port.removeClass('removed');
    port.removeClass('edit-portlet');
  }
};
```

Grabbing the "event's target" will ensure that you are only addressing the item that was actually clicked.  And note that angular uses $event to pass the event to a function.

I would also clean it up a bit combining the class modification lines and targeting the specific parent (in case you ever modify the DOM) using .closest():

```
scope.removePortlet = function(ev) {
  var port = $(ev.target).closest('.parent-portlet');
  port.addClass('removed, edit-portlet');
};

scope.addPortlet = function(ev) {
  var port = $(ev.target).closest('.parent-portlet');
  if (portlet.hasClass('removed')) {
    port.removeClass('removed, edit-portlet');
  }
};
```

Comment: var port = $(ev.target).closest('.parent-portlet'); worked great for me! Thanks for the solution and also the suggestions. Well appreciated.

Comment: It was my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `$element` to your controller, then, use it as the context for the `$` selector.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $element) {
  $scope.addPortlet = function(portlet) {
    console.log($('.add-back', $element));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="parent-portlet">
    <div class="portlet-titlebar" ng-click="toggleCollapsed($event)">
      <span class="remove" ng-click="removePortlet(portlet)">
       Remove
      </span>
      <span class="add-back" ng-click="addPortlet(portlet)">
       Add Back
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[For more info about it](https://jaketrent.com/post/angularjs-find-element-in-context/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-class` instead. Here's an example of changing background colors with classes:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.portlet = {
    classes: {
      "parent-portlet": true,
      "edit-portlet": false,
      "removed": false
    }
  }
  
  $scope.removePortlet = function(portlet) {
    portlet.classes.removed = true;
    portlet.classes["edit-portlet"] = true;
  };
  
  $scope.addPortlet = function(portlet) {
    portlet.classes.removed = false;
    portlet.classes["edit-portlet"] = false;
  };
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

.parent-portlet {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent-portlet.removed {
  background-color: #c00;
}

.parent-portlet button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-class="portlet.classes">
    <div class="portlet-titlebar">
      <button class="remove" ng-click="removePortlet(portlet)">
        Remove
      </button>
      <button class="add-back" ng-click="addPortlet(portlet)">
        Add Back
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```